# Identities involving product pairs of the Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta

Is there a relatively simple proof for the following related identities (shown true in Mathematica only) involving the the analytically continued Riemann Zeta Function, $\zeta(s)$?

$$\zeta (s) \zeta (1-s)=\left(\zeta \left(s^*\right) \zeta \left(1-s^*\right)\right)^*\tag{1}$$
and
$$\zeta (s) \zeta \left(1-s^*\right)=\left(\zeta \left(s^*\right) \zeta (1-s)\right)^*\tag{2}$$

$s$ is complex and $s^*$ is the complex conjugate of $s$.

I presume any proof will involve some variation of Riemann's Functional Equation,

$$\zeta(s)=2^s \pi^{s-1}\sin(\pi s/2)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)$$

but this does not seem straight forward and I can't see how.

If we now assume $s=\frac{1}{2}+i z$ and $s^*=\frac{1}{2}-i z$ then $\zeta(s)\zeta(1-s)=(\zeta(s^*)\zeta(1-s^*))^*$ seems to always be a real product whatever the value of $z$, but $\zeta(s)\zeta(1-s^*)=(\zeta(s^*)\zeta(1-s))^*$ seems to only have a real product when both the Zeta Functions involved are zero or $z=0$. Assuming this is correct, does this difference follow from the proof above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually much simpler than it appears: by the [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle), *any* analytic function $f(z)$ that is real on the real axis satisfies $f(\overline z) = \overline{f(z)}$ and thus $f(z) = \overline{f(\overline z)}$.

Comment: Thanks, and related to the method of mirror charges a bonus.